# How to find specific value of html element (such as h1) with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to find the numbers of users on this [website](https://feds.lol), using node.js, but I'm not sure of what process I can do to get it. The value is subclassed under multiple divs with different class names. Right now I will just be console.logging it but I'm going to do more with the data later on.

I was suggested to use the package "puppeteer", but I'm not sure how this would fetch it or what to do with it to fetch it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the data you need is in the RAW HTML (not something added to the page with Javascript in the page), then you can use cheerio.  You fetch the HTML, feed it to Cheerio which will parse the HTML into a server-side DOM and then you can use jQuery-like DOM queries to locate content in the DOM.  Cheerio is lighter weight than puppeteer if you don't need to "run" the Javascript in the page and are just trying to parse the HTML.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Puppeteer and obtain the value via a query string. The typical code looks like this:

> ```
> const pt= require('puppeteer')
>
> async function getText(){
>
>    //launch browser in headless mode
>    const browser = await pt.launch()
>
>    //browser new page
>    const page = await browser.newPage()
>
>    //launch URL
>    await page.goto('https://feds.lol/')
>
>    //identify element
>    const f = await page.$("QUERY_STRIG")
>
>    //obtain text
>    const text = await (await f.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue()
>    console.log("Text is: " + text)
> }
>
> getText()
> ```

However, I see this website is protected by Captcha